# How come the gas usage of an empty fallback function is not integer?

Tags: gas, fallback-function

I am trying to compute the gas usage of an empty (i.e., the most basic) fallback function.

My on-chain code (compiled via Truffle 4.1.15):

```
pragma solidity 0.4.25;

contract MyContract {
    function() external payable {}
}
```

My off-chain code (executed via Truffle 4.1.15 and Ganache 6.2.5):

```
contract("MyContract", function(accounts) {
    it("Test", async function() {
        const myContract    = await artifacts.require("MyContract").new();
        const balanceBefore = await web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[0]);
        const response      = await web3.eth.sendTransaction({from: accounts[0], to: myContract.address, value: 1000000});
        const balanceAfter  = await web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[0]);
        const gasUsed       = balanceBefore.minus(balanceAfter).div(web3.eth.gasPrice);
        console.log("gasUsed =", gasUsed.toFixed());
    });
});
```

The result I get is `gasUsed = 21018.00005`.

I've made sure that `web3.eth.gasPrice` doesn't change throughout the execution (it remains 20000000000, as configured in my `ganache-cli` command line).

So what exactly am I missing here?

Thank you!

Comment: This done in remix using JavaScript VM produces an integer as it should (21018).

Comment: @Jaime: Yet, it doesn't explain what is wrong in my process of computing the gas usage.

Comment: You seem to be having numerical issues and this is unrelated to ethereum or the smart contract. Just out of curiosity you could try dividing your numbers (balanceBefore, balance after and gassPrice) by 1000000 before calculating gasUsed

Comment: @Jaime: I disagree on your statement that this is unrelated to ethereum or the smart contract, since this is how one can compute the total gas usage of a given transaction. Again - unless I have something wrong in my computation process, which you haven't been able to point out as of yet (so until then, I don't think that it can be regarded as a purely "numerical issue"). Thank you.

Comment: You said "this is how one can compute the total gas usage of a given transaction", but the gas used is in the receipt of the transaction so you do not have to calculate it like this. Also, this is a numerical issue. I did this using the javaScript VM and then again in python, I got the expected results. This is not related to ethereum.

Comment: @Jaime: Sorry, but the response from `web3.eth.sendTransaction` doesn't contain `receipt.gasUsed` (I would have used it directly otherwise).

Comment: you can get the hash returned by `sendTransaction` and wait for the receipt using web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(hash [, callback])` then you can get receipt.gasUsed.